# Fully OO Ftp library for php

Tags: php, class, ftp

I was trying to build an application that will download some files from various ftp servers to a local directory. Later I would upload them to other ftp servers.

The application is built using Zend framework.

The thing is I can't find a class to handle ftp download/upload functions in Zend framework.

The only class available is `Zend_File_Transfer` which has the following comment:

> Note: Limitation
>
> The current implementation of Zend_File_Transfer is
> limited to HTTP Post Uploads. Other adapters supporting downloads and
> other protocols will be added in future  releases. Unimplemented
> methods will throw an exception. For now, you should use
> Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http directly. As soon as there are
> multiple adapters available you can use a common interface.

I need to be able to do the following:

- Upload multiple files.
- Get a remote directory listing of all files.
- Set validators
- Set filters
- Set paths
- Rename files
- Wrapper for downloads
- Exceptions for various errors during operation.

Is there a solution to this problem in Zend framework? Could you recommend an alternative library for ftp operations ?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

- I checked the PEAR package and unfortunately it's still in alpha
  release. Moreover their functions return errors not exception once a
  problem occur like download failure or remote path weren't found.
- Unfortunately Skjb_Ftp isn't complete as many functions don't have an implementation.

Comment: have you tried with the [native one](http://php.net/ftp) or the [PEAR package](http://pear.php.net/package/Net_FTP)?

Comment: @Gordon Yes I tried to use the native function, but they lacked certain feature like throwing exception whenever an error occur which required me to build a layer above the library. The layer itself had many problems :( Does the PEAR package support these features ?

Comment: I dont know. I have never used it. I am just giving links to obvious available choices.

Comment: @Gordon I checked the PEAR package and unfortunately it's still in alpha release. Moreover their functions return errors not exception once a problem occur like download failure or remote path weren't found.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this php5 wrapper for the builtin FTP functions: https://github.com/dg/ftp-php it has some exception handling stuff you might be able to use.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fully OOP php ftp library i build it in my self (hard working), its unit tested and it will works for your purposes perfectly. [php-ftp-client](https://github.com/lazzard/php-ftp-client)

Answer (score 1):

Here is great library for it: https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client

Comment: doesn't work. connection get established and lists dirs too , but can't pass file

Comment: my bad, I needed to call pasv() function

Answer (score 0):

There is a [proposal for Zend_Ftp](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Ftp+-+Steven+Brown) that you might be able to use. Failing that, there is [Skjb_Ftp](http://code.google.com/p/skjb-zf/source/browse/trunk/library/Skjb/).

I cannot vouch for the completeness or validity of either of these solutions, as I haven't used either, but it should be something to get you started. Some of the functionality you require is missing, but it shouldn't be too difficult to add it using the [FTP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ftp.php).

Comment: I read the proposal, but I am not sure if it's complete or tested enough to use on a production server. I'll look into Skjb_Ftp.

Comment: update: Unfortunately Skjb_Ftp isn't complete as many functions have a comment inside them written as "unfinished" :(

Comment: Seems that many implementations are like that :-) Some more examples at [PHP Classes](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/6789.html) (PHP4, eurgh) and [CodeIgniter](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Ftp.php). Given your existing application is built on ZF, I'd suggest incorporating these into your own file transfer adapter. You could even get involved with the [ZF2 community](http://framework.zend.com/zf2) and see if anyone is working on anything that you can backport.